# Record device audio output with AudioUnit

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

We need to record the device audio output from cable or bluetooth headset speakers. For example if user listens to some song when Music app runs in background we want to record this song. Is it possible to implement output recording with AudioUnit? We use PalayAndRecord category for shared audioSession with AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general you can not listen to the output from another app. There is inter app audio and audio unit technology that enables this, but the connection must be arranged by both apps. It is not possible to just eavesdrop on whatever the user outputs from the device.